# Play live H264 stream in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, codec, android-mediacodec

### Situation :

I am working on android.

I have some live data(Similar to RTP packets) coming into my ethernet port. By following RFC 6184 specification, I have defragmented the NAL units and saved them into a file.

I am exactly following the same process that is being followed by [ffmpeg here.](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.4/rtpdec__h264_8c_source.html) So, the format of the data being saved is H264  byte stream data.

### Question :

While the data is being saved in the file, I want to display the already available video data as a live stream.

How can I do this in android?

### PS:

I am able to play the data in a mediaplayer once the data is completely saved. What I want is that is there a way I can do it in a live fashion. As in, I don't have to wait till I receive all my video data.

Comment: Have you seen this site: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

Comment: @MorrisonChang Not yet. Is Mediacodec the best solution for my situation? In order to supply the buffers to mediacodec, I have to parse the file again starting from "start sequence" and iterate throughout to find the complete buffers. I was wondering if there is any other good way.

Comment: You might want to describe your encoding/video processing architecture in some more detail (i.e. how are you transforming your live data - C/C++ library) as you mention both byte buffers and a H264 byte stream. So I'm not clear about 'I have to parse the file again'.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I am receiving NAL units on ethernet port. I have my own application which captures these packets and extracts teh payload out of it. The payload is of type RTP format. Hence following the guidelines of RFC6184, I am defragmenting the NALunits and saving them into a file(This code is in C). While this is going on in one thread, from the android application, I want to display the already parsed & saved data in real-time.

Comment: @MorrisonChang If using mediacodec here, I have to start parsing the file from "start sequence" to the next "start_sequence" to find out the size of each frame and then read that much amount of data and then pass it to mediacodec. This looks little time consuming. No?

Comment: I keep imagining that you should be doing all of this before even writing to a file as any IO, the actual save to file operation, would be the most expensive (even on flash). Unless you don't have access to the C library to buffer and inspect. Or there is some other complication I'm not aware of.